# Can't install theme after installing Spotify

Tags: command-line, apt, software-installation, updates, themes

I recently installed Spotify successfully. Now, I am trying to install a theme. I successfully downloaded the package in the terminal with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tiheum/equinox
```

But when I try to update the package with:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install faenza-icon-theme
```

it continually tries to update the Spotify package which I had previously installed and no mention of theme file.

Do I need to clear the terminal somehow before I can install a new package?

Answer (score 0):

A few points:

- PPAs are usually keyed for particular versions
- When you add a PPA to your system using `add-apt-repository` it will try to add it for your current version.
- [This PPA](https://launchpad.net/~tiheum/+archive/equinox) doesn't have a Saucy version.

If you're on Saucy, you're not going to be able to use it as is.

To work around this you could either edit the sources file (it'll be lurking in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`) to change the dist from `saucy` to `raring` (the last release).

Or just download the debs from launchpad and install them manually (`sudo dpkg -i filename.deb` or double-click).